# How have a lot of labels Data in chart.js

Tags: javascript, c#, charts, chart.js

I am using chart.js to create a linear Chart, my data would be loan amount that is either 180, payment that is for 15 years mortgage or 360 payment that is for  30 years. What I am sending to the chart is Loan amount for Data that is in vertical line, for the Horizontal line I have 3 Labels that is 0 – 15 Years – 30 Years- To show the chart correctly the labels should be 360 labels that I don’t want to show all, how I can manage it?

```
var lineChartData = {
    labels: ["0", "15 Years", "30 Years"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: '# of Votes',
            fillColor: "",
            data: [0]
        }
    ]

}


 function UpdateLineChart(data) {
    debugger;
    //Set data returned from Server
    lineChartData.datasets[0].fillColor = data.colorString;
    lineChartData.datasets[0].data = data.lineChartData;
    //Update the Pie Chart
    var canvasForLineChart = document.getElementById("canvasForLineChart");
    var context2DLine = canvasForLineChart.getContext("2d");
    new Chart(context2DLine).Line(lineChartData);
}
```

The data in the Chart is coming from C# and is Array of 180 and data looks like:

```
    0: 200000
    1:199999
    2:198988
    .....
    179:180
    180:0
```

How I can have it work with the just 3 labels?

when I have 3 labels my chart is look like this:
[image]

so I have to add 360 labels like:

```
    var lineChartData = {
    labels: ["0",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "15 Years",
         "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "30 Years"],
    datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "",
            data: [0]
        }
    ]

}
```

Then my chart is look like this:[image]

Comment: On axe config, set maxTicksLimit:
`scales: {
     yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 2
        }
....
`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8usLg5r4/2/

Comment: @NilsonMorais but you only sent 3 values (65, 59, 80) To the chart I have 360 to send what should I do?

Comment: Try to Increment autoSkipPadding: https://jsfiddle.net/8usLg5r4/4/

Comment: @NilsonMorais Can you please look at my chart that I added to the question. Some how I still not coming with the curve correctly.